# Geometric Brownian Motion in R

Tags: r, simulation, random-walk

When simulating a Geometric Brownian Motion in R with GBM formula from sde package:

```
GBM(x, r, sigma, T, N)
```

"r" is drift in this case, right? Since it says in the package manual "r = interest rate" I'm not sure how to enter the parameter specification - e.g. 5% - would I enter r=5 or r=0.05?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Cheers, Ana :)

Comment: Hi, if it's a rate i would try 0.05!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, rate refers to drift rate - the average value at which the average of this process changes. As such, r in this case directly corresponds to the μ that you are used to seeing when discussing Geometric Brownian Motion.

To comply with the vocabulary of the help docs I'd say that entering .05 is correct since that is a rate.

Answer (score 1):

```
# for loop
miu = .08
sigma = .2
S = numeric(90)
S[1] = 4780
dt = 1/365

for(i in 1:89){
  eps = rnorm(1)
  S[i+1] = S[i] + miu*S[i]*dt + sigma*eps*S[i]*sqrt(dt)
}
plot(S, type = "l", col = "red")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
# for loop
miu = .08
sigma = .2
S = numeric(90)
S[1] = 4780
dt = 1/365

for(i in 1:89){
    eps = rnorm(1)
    S[i+1] = S[i] + miu*S[i]*dt + sigma*eps*S[i]*sqrt(dt)



S_matrix <- mat.or.vec(50,90)
S_matrix[,1] <- 4780


for(j in 1:50){
  for(i in 1:89){
    eps = rnorm(1)
    S_matrix[j,i+1] = S_matrix[j,i] + miu*S_matrix[j,i]*dt + sigma*eps*S_matrix[j,i]*sqrt(dt)
  }
}
 
S_matrix
```